# Как запустить функцию в нескольких потоках?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть функция, которую нужно несколько раз запустить с разными аргументами, но одновременно. Как это сделать проще, чем запускать несколько экземпляров программы одновременно *.bat* файлом с разными аргументами запуска?

Функция выглядит вот так, и каждый её экземпляр гарантированно не ссылается на общие данные:

```
static void getData(int firstId, int lastId, int fileId){...};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360555/how-to-pass-parameters-to-threadstart-method-in-thread Попробуйте почитать тут, вроде есть ответ на вопрос

Comment: зачем функцию с возвращаемым значением void называть getData?

Comment: Спасибо больше, как раз то что и нужно было

Answer (score 6):

На основе вашего метода сформируйте [Task'и](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) и далее воспользуйтесь методом `Task.WaitAll()`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff());
        Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff());
        Task task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff());
        Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3);
                Console.WriteLine("All threads complete");
    }

    static void doStuff()
    {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
```